# Access activity context from runnable interface

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runnable, android-context

I have this setup

MainActivity Class creates BTHandler which is a utility class. It passes activity context and application context.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
    currentBT = new BTHandle(this, MainActivity.this);
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        ...
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
}
```

This is the Utiliy class. It uses both context for some computation and when is required it creates ConnectThread, to start a connection with a BT device. It passes the activity context so ConnectThread can send a message through the Handler.

```
class BTHandle { 
    private final Context mainActivityContext;
    private final Activity mainActivity;
    ...
    public BTHandle(final Context context, final Activity activity){
        mainActivityContext = context;
        mainActivity = activity;
    }
    f(){
        ConnectThread connectAsClient = new ConnectThread(mainActivityContext, BTDevice, mBluetoothAdapter, BTUuid);
        new Thread(connectAsClient).start();
    }

}
```

And Finally here comes the error. This is ConnectThread. I want to send a message from here to MainActivity. But compiler says it cant resolve handler. So I'm guessing the context doesn't come trough it.

```
public class ConnectThread implements Runnable {
     private final Context mainActivity;
     public ConnectThread(Context context, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothAdapter adapter, UUID BT_UUID) {
     ...
     mainActivity = context;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
         ...
       Message completeMessage = mainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(555, "CONNECTED");
       completeMessage.sendToTarget();
     }
}
```

How can I pass the context in the right way so ConnectThread can see handler?

Comment: What's the exact error message? From what I can see you're trying to reference a handler from a `Context` object.. Your `Handler` is a part of your `MainActivity`

Comment: `handler` is not a member of the `Context` class.  If you would like access to this field, you will need to cast your `mainActivity` to a `MainActivity`.

Comment: oh I see the error. I got it wrong. handler is not part of the context class. @Stefan the error is: cannot find symbol variable handler. So, how would ConnectThread can see handler in mainActivity.

Comment: @JoeC casting works. thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pass in the MainActivity object all the way down to ConnectRunnable i.e :

```
private final MainActivity mainActivity;
public ConnectThread(MainActivity context, BluetoothDevice device,
BluetoothAdapter adapter, UUID BT_UUID) {
 ...
 mainActivity = context;
 }
```

Or change your call to:

```
 Message completeMessage = 
((MainActivity)(Activity)mainActivity)).handler.obtainMessage(555, "CONNECTED");
```

Also, your handler is bound to leak memory. 
Have a look at this for the fix: [How to Leak a Context: Handlers & Inner Classes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a public and static MainActvity variable and use it in your other class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
public static MainActivity mainActivity;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
mainActivity = this;
currentBT = new BTHandle(this, MainActivity.this);
}

public Handler handler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    ...
    super.handleMessage(msg);
}
};
}
```

and in your other class :

```
public class ConnectThread implements Runnable {
private MainActivity mainActivity;
 public ConnectThread(Context context, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothAdapter adapter, UUID BT_UUID) {
 ...
 mainActivity = MainActivity.mainActivity;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
     ...
   Message completeMessage = mainActivity.handler.obtainMessage(555, "CONNECTED");
   completeMessage.sendToTarget();
 }
}
```